# how to use classes themselves as method parameters?

Tags: c#, class, methods

Its been a while but i need to convert some custom code into C# (i think it was called emeralds or something somebody else gave to me). there is a certain method that takes a class(any class without any object conversions). this is the code im trying to convert.

```
      class  management
        Accessor current_class
        Accessor class_Stack

      def call(next_class)          #method, called global, takes a "class" instead 
                                       #of a variable, kinda odd
        stack.push(current_class)      #stack handling
        current_class = next_class.new #makes a new instance of specified next_class

      end
    end
```

next_class seems to be any class related to a base class and assigns a new instance of them to a variable called currentClass. there are other "methods" that do something similar. I've tried setting the parameter type to "object", but loses all the the "next_class" attributes that are needed. this is my attempt at it

```
     public class management {
        public Stack stack;           
        public Someclass currentClass; 

      public void Call(object nextClass) {
        stack.push(currentClass);   // stack handling    
        currentClass = new nextClass(); // conversion exception, otherwise loss of type

    }
    }
```

IS this even possible in C# 
another thing this language seems to able to keep attributes(methods too) from Child classes when you cast them as a base class. e.g cast green bikes as just bikes but it will still be green

can somebody point me in the right direction here? or do i need to rewrite it and change the way it does things?

Comment: @EdS. is correct; however, please do callback once you have read up on **C# Generics** if you have further questions.

Comment: also the guy go back to, the language was "Ruby 3"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is Generics and I think also, based on the fact that you call a method, Interfaces.

So your Interface will define "new" and the Class will inherit from the interface.

You can then pass the class as a generic and call the Interface method of "new" on it.

So;

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  void newMethod();
}

public class MyClass1 : IMyInterface
{
    public void newMethod()
    {
      //Do what the method says it will do.
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        MyClass1 classToSend = new MyClass1();
        test<IMyInterface>(classToSend);
    }

    public void test<T>(T MyClass) where T : IMyInterface
    {
        MyClass.newMethod();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

And check out "dynamic" in C# 4.0.  I say this because if you don't know what the method is until runtime you can define it as dynamic and you are basically telling the compiler that "trust me the method will be there".

This is in case you can't use generics because the methods you call will be different for each class.

Comment: ahh now i get it... so i have to do this for like 20 other methods lol. I was confused for a while for which class inherits. thanks for the help

Comment: No probs.  Hope you get there

Comment: all the methods in each class(not all of them just relevant ones) will be the same, since they usually call the same method in the base class then add there own stuff to it. well that's good news

Comment: that is good news and you can then use an interface and generics.  Good luck

Comment: done now to "invent" the base classes the guy apparently did not have... oh god...lol

Comment: after implementing the snippet you gave me, it seems to be still giving me "cannot implicitly convert type" error, i also tried "inverting" your code... Generics seems practical.

Comment: also note that the "new" method in the custom code is really the equivalent of the new keyword in C#, with the exception this automatically calls the function "initialize " incase you thought it was a function...

Comment: got it to work... seems you were a little confused on what i was asking, through a little research and editing it finally works, thanks for help